# Number of different trivalent graphs of size $n$ associated with a general Lie algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, graph-theory

If $L$ is a general Lie algebra and a vertex of a trivalent graph $G$ symbolizes the (symmetrized) structure constant tensor $C_{ijk}$, we know that $C$ is fully antisymmetric, and the Jacobi relation holds (IHX for $C$). This means any face $F$ of sizes $1,2,3$ can be reduced. It is known under this condition only Yutsis graphs remain. But this is not the end: Applying IHX, the 6j symbol has the value $1/2/d$ (where $d$ is the dimension of $L$), the 9j symbol vanishes identically (if I remember correctly), and the two 12j symbols will be related to each other.

The obvious question: Can all Yutsis graphs (not only 6j and 9j)  $Y$ be evaluated to have some value $Y(d)$ identical for all $L$ (a sentence in "Birdtracks", where only semisimple $L$ are dealt with using purely graphical methods, might imply that) or do some "basic" graphs remain? (I once tried IHX on all nonequivalent vertices up to 15j, methinks the latter holds - e.g. all vertices of both 12j are equivalent, and thus one IHX relation can be derived.) If yes, how many?

BTW, in this case, the values should be different for different $L$ and might be interesting for the classification of (solvable) Lie algebras.